# Function imported from a module in Typescript isn't recognised as a function in compiled JS?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a Typescript project, which calls a function from a `module.js` module. Here is my initial code:

```
//app.ts
import { MobileServiceUser, setCache, getCache } from "nativescript-azure-mobile-apps/user";
export function onLoginTap(args) {
    console.log("tap");
    ai.busy = true;
    var cache = getCache();
}
```

if I use the VSCode "go to definition" feature, then `getCache()` goes to the import statement at the top, if I do this again, then I go to:

```
//module.ts
declare module "nativescript-azure-mobile-apps/user" {

    export class MobileServiceUser {
        mAuthenticationToken: string;
        mUserId: string;

        constructor(o: { userId: string; });
    }

    export function setCache(user: MobileServiceUser): void;
    export function getCache(): MobileServiceUser;
}
```

When I execute the code and the `var cache = user_1.getCache();` line is executed, my app crashes, throwing error:

> TypeError: user_1.getCache is not a function
>   File: "/data/data/inc.tangra.azuremobileservicessample/files/app/main-page.js, line: 94, column: 23

app.ts looks like this compiled to js:

```
var user_1 = require("nativescript-azure-mobile-apps/user");
function onLoginTap(args) {
    console.log("tap");
    ai.busy = true;
    var cache = user_1.getCache();
}
```

Why isn't the code recognising the imported function?

Update: this [repo](https://github.com/georgeedwards/nativescript-azure-mobile-apps) shows the project structure (the first page of code is in sample/main-page.ts

Comment: Where is your actual "nativescript-azuer-mobile-apps/user.js or .ts file?

Comment: @Nathanael, it is in the node_modules folder. I am successfully using other exported classes from that module

Comment: in your `module.ts`, I'm not sure of typescript (never used it), but I know JS will just flat out refuse if you put a semicolon inside an object, like you have for `constructor(o: { userId: string; });` Try removing the semicolon after `string` and see if that helps, or if the error changes.

Comment: @Jhecht I'm afraid I still get the same result...

Comment: Why a `declare module` in a file `.ts` ?

Comment: @Paleo So I can reference it as a type. I then extend it in in platform specific classes (this is a NativeScript plugin which targets multiple mobile operating systems)

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards But your error, at run time, is that `user_1.getCache` is not a function. Maybe you declare a missing function `getCache()`?

Comment: @Paleo not quite sure what you mean? Are you saying I might have missed the function definition in my extension class? If so, TS would throw an error to say the class incorrectly extends my d.ts file - which it doesn't.

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards I can't help you. But, for an error at run time, I advise you to understand first what happens in JavaScript, and why: `user_1.getCache is not a function`.

Comment: @Paleo sure, but definition tracking doesn't work with JS in VSCode?

Comment: @GeorgeEdwards I looked at your linked repo.  the user.ios and user.android files are completely empty.  No function in those files, means that function won't exist...